# Android Studio project build with deployGate gradle plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, deployment, terminal, gradle-plugin

I just started using [DeployGate](https://deploygate.com) with my Android application in Android Studio and I want to use the [gradle plugin](https://github.com/DeployGate/gradle-deploygate-plugin/blob/master/README.md), to upload my new versions (I think it is for that, or had I misunderstood it?).

I finally achieved that my project build successful with my modified build.gradle (Module:app):

```
apply plugin: 'deploygate'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

deploygate {
    userName = "[myUsername]" //yes, I replaced it with my own
    token = "[myAPIKey]"      // also
    apks {
        release {
            sourceFile = file("C:\\AndroidStudioProjects\\MyApp\\app\\app-release.apk")
        }

        debug {
            sourceFile = file("C:\\AndroidStudioProjects\\MyApp\\app\\build\\outputs\\apk\\app-debug.apk")

            //Below is optional
            //message = "test upload2 sample"
            //visibility = "public" 
            //distributionKey = "[distribution_key]"
            //releaseNote = "release note sample"
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "bendaf.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 13
        versionName "1.2.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.deploygate:sdk:3.1'
}
```

but when I try to execute the command `gradle uploadDeployGate` in terminal it sais **BUILD FAILED**. (I am not too experienced with gradle, so am I doing it right?)

my stacktrace is:

```
    * Exception is:             
    org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
        at     org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:54)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:190)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:39)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:521)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:82)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:31)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:129)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyPlugin(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:117)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$200(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$3.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:131)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractPluginAware.apply(AbstractPluginAware.java:37)
        at org.gradle.api.Project$apply$0.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.apply(ProjectScript.groovy:34)
        at org.gradle.api.Script$apply$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at build_78pi66j0mnhjns6vp3krggobhd.run(C:\AndroidStudioProjects\VivagoDatatransmission\app\build.gradle:25)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:52)
        ... 31 more         
Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Gradle version 2.2 is required. Current version is 2.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\An
droidStudioProjects\VivagoDatatransmission\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.2-all.zip
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.checkGradleVersion(BasePlugin.groovy:436)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.configureProject(BasePlugin.groovy:265)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_apply_closure1.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy:252)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_apply_closure1.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.SpanRecorders$2.call(SpanRecorders.groovy:52)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:48)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.SpanRecorders.record(SpanRecorders.groovy:54)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.apply(BasePlugin.groovy:251)
        at com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin.super$2$apply(AppPlugin.groovy)
        at com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin.apply(AppPlugin.groovy:66)
        at com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin.apply(AppPlugin.groovy)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer.providePlugin(DefaultPluginContainer.java:188)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer.addPluginInternal(DefaultPluginContainer.java:137)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer.apply(DefaultPluginContainer.java:103)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyPlugin(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:115)
        ... 40 more
```

According to the error message the problem is in my gradle-wrapper.properties, but it have the right gradle version, I think:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

so what is the problem here? Or am I doing something wrong? How should I upload the app automatically to DeployGate? 
Thanks, for the answer.

Comment: It looks like you are using `gradle` itself, so it doesn't read gradle-wrapper.properties. Try `gradlew` (Gradle wrapper) in your project directory.

Comment: Thank you, I've execute the command `gradlew uploadDeployGate` and it's working! Could you explain it a little more what is the difference between the two command in your answer, so I could accept it? Thank you! :)

Comment: My pleasure. Glad to hear it worked out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running globally-installed `gradle` command which doesn't respect `gradle-wrapper.properties` you edited. Instead, you need to run `gradlew` command.

Gradle wrapper is [the preferred way of starting a Gradle build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) that allows you to run a specific version of Gradle for each project. With the wrapper, all you have to do to build your project is:

1. Checkout the repository
2. Run `gradlew`

That's all. You don't even need to install Gradle beforehand, the wrapper takes care of everything, so you can build your application anywhere and easily migrate into continuous integration.